# Processing - Resize canvas based on jpg dimensions

Tags: java, image, canvas, processing

I have a basic program where stock images form the background for a larger program - but a number of the images have slightly different sizes compared to each other.

My initial code loads up the background image and tries to set the canvas size based on the image dimensions:

```
    PImage bg;
    void setup() {
    bg = loadImage("102.jpg");
    println(bg.width);
    println(bg.height);
    wWidth = bg.width;
    wHeight = bg.height;
    size(wWidth,wHeight);
    }
    void draw() {
      background(bg);
    }
```

I get 'IllegalStateException' error
bg.width and bg.height are 806 and 1229, when I include 806 and 1229 instead of wWidth and wHeight respectively, I get the output I want - would I need to declare the size() in a different way? Or would it be simpler to try and resize the jpg files via processing to the same size?

Comment: You need to scale the image, not just change the size.

Comment: Thanks- that solved my problem - didn't even think about resizing it initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would've worked in Processing 2, but [things changed in Processing 3](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0#things-that-may-break-your-2x-sketches): you simply need to use [`settings()`](https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html).

Here's a minimal sketch that loads in image and changes the sketch size to the image dimensions:

```
PImage img;

void settings(){
  img = loadImage("https://processing.org/img/processing-web.png");
  println(img.width, img.height);
  size(img.width, img.height);
}
void setup(){
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

You're code would look something like:

```
PImage bg;
int wWidth;
int wHeight;

void settings(){
  bg = loadImage("102.jpg");
  println(bg.width);
  println(bg.height);
  wWidth = bg.width;
  wHeight = bg.height;
  size(wWidth, wHeight);
}

void setup() {
  
}
void draw() {
  background(bg);
}
```

As slightly simpler version would be:

```
PImage bg;

void settings(){
  bg = loadImage("102.jpg");
  println(bg.width);
  println(bg.height);
  size(bg.width, bg.height);
}

void setup() {
  
}
void draw() {
  background(bg);
}
```

The `wWidth, wHeight` variables might be redundant since Processing's `width,height` variables store the same data after `size()` has been called.